# Displaying HTML code

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

In PHP I can use the following to stop HTML from rendering, so it actually displays html as text on the web page:

```
$html = "<div>Some text</div>";

echo htmlentities($html);
```

How do I do the same with asp.net pages (vb.net).  I am using .NET 3.5.

Comment: Did everyone who ansered this question already know the answer or did they, like me, do one simple google search and get the answer from the first result in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
var html = @"<div>Some text</div>";
Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(html));
```

which is the **exact** translation of your snippet.

BTW, you can find more info on `Server.HtmlEncode` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) for this:

```
<%= Server.HtmlEncode("<div>Some text</div>") %>
```

In .NET 4 you could use a shorthand for this:

```
<%: "<div>Some text</div>" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Server.HtmlEncode("`<div>Some text</div>`");
```